# The absolute positioning element expands the parent element

Tags: css

[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/zjga9m52/)

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.div1 {
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
}

.div2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  right: -80px;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2"></div>
</div>
```

dom 'div2' is a absolute positioning element,and the dom 'div1' is a relative positioning element,when I set the left property of the 'div2' to '-80px',it push off the parent dom,and let the scrollbar show,who know why....thanks to help me!

Comment: Can you edit and add what result are you expecting? Why do you add `-80px`?

Comment: What result are you expecting? You *are* actually setting `.div2` to be -80px to the right. When it's absolutely positioned that's exactly what should happen. If you don't want the element to flow out of `.div1`, then just set `overflow: hidden;` on `.div1`.

Comment: What are you expecting. Do you mean to have right as `right: 80px`? Or did you want it to flow outside of the parent?

Comment: Thank you for your patient comments,I expect 'div2'  float above the 'div1',if set overflow:hidden on 'div1',A small part of 'div2' will be hidden,I want show 'div2' entirety,and don't want the scrollbar show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The absolute property is set relatively to the DOM's ancestor element, so -80px is outside of the first div, and therefore it's "push" out of div1.
A possible solution, is to use -80's compliment, or relative instead.

Comment: Doesn't it mean that the elements are definitely positioned out of the document flow?Why is the scroll bar showing up?,I want show 'div2' entirety,and don't want the scrollbar show.